# as3 ShineMP3Encoder issue (clicking sound when mp3 audio starts)

Tags: actionscript-3, shinemp3encoder

After recording a sound and converting it into `wav`...

```
var enco:WaveEncoder=new WaveEncoder();
var o:ByteArray=enco.encode(soundO,1,16,44100);
```

I pass it to ShineMP3Encoder

```
_mp3_encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(o);
_mp3_encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMP3EncoderComplete, false, 0, true);
_mp3_encoder.start();
```

`onMP3EncoderComplete` has two vars

```
var mp3:ByteArray = _mp3_encoder.mp3Data;
var wav:ByteArray = _mp3_encoder.wavData;
```

wav audio is normal, but mp3 almost always (99%) has a clicking sound when audio begins.
Here's a picture from SoundForge app.

[image]

We can see these two files are identical, but mp3 has a clicking sound at the beginning.

Is it my system/hardware/compiler problem or it's something else?

btw I tried some online swf example of ShineMP3Encoder and it has same issue. So probably that's not my compiler problem

Comment: I never used this encoder but isn't it this issue https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy/issues/3 ? What are you targeting? Can't you user original lame encoder, would be probably better/more flexible.

Comment: Thanx it helped. I'd never solve it by myself. I think your comment is quite helpful, I'll accept it if you place it as an answer

Comment: I don't know if I should post the answer with that. I only give you a link to issue that someone other solved.